# JS / JQuery character problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, character

I have a code which has a character that JS is not handling properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $.getJSON("http://sjama.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?",
        function (data){
            for (var i=0; i<data.posts.length; i++){

                    var blog = data.posts[i];

                    var id = blog.id;
                    var type = blog.type;

                    var photo = blog.photo-url-250;

                    if (type == "photo"){

                        $("#blog_holder").append('<div class="blog_item_holder"><div class="blog_item_top"><img src='+photo+'/></div><div class="blog_item_bottom">caption will go here</div></div>');
                    }

            }

        }); <!-- end $.getJSON

});
```

The problem is with this line:

```
   var photo = blog.photo-url-250;
```

after "blog." it reads the "url" part weirdly because of the dash (-) in between.

What can I do to sort this problem out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the property in square brackets with a string literal.

```
blog["photo-url-250"];
```

Likewise, when creating an object property with invalid name characters (such as the hyphen), you will use a string literal.

```
var blog = {
               someProperty: "someValue",     // Name has valid characters.
               "some-property": "some-value"  // This name requires a string literal.
           }
```

Valid characters are letters, numbers, underscore and $.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead

```
var photo = blog['photo-url-250'];
```

Read this ( http://javascript.about.com/od/variablesandoperators/a/vop04.htm ) for rules that apply to variable naming..

Your code could be read as `set photo to blog.photo minus url minus 250`

```
var photo = blog.photo - url - 250;
```

Answer (score 1):

can you write it as blog["photo-url-250"]

Answer (score 1):

That's a property that should be wrapped in `[]` eg:

```
var photo = blog["photo-url-250"];
```

Answer (score 1):

use other notation:

```
var photo = blog['photo-url-250'];
```